# WPF CurrentUICulture on CurrentThread changing

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, internationalization, cultureinfo

I have a program I'm writing which changes the program culture on startup. In App.cs:

```
if (tokens[0].Equals("english"))
                {
                    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture =
                        new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");
                }
                else if (tokens[0].Equals("portuguese"))
                {
                    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture =
                        new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("pt-BR");
                }
                else if (tokens[0].Equals("spanish"))
                {

                    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture =
                        new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("es-CO");

                }
```

I print out the thread and CurrentUICulture name right after this switch., and it seems to be fine.

However, then in a GainKeyboardFocus event in a TextBox, I different things to happens depending on the culture. However, it doesn't seem to work properly. When I print out the thread and CurrentUICulture, the thread appears to be the same (both are thread 1), but the CurrentUICulture is back to the default.

Comment: I test it right now.
Add set UICulture in App constructor and check it in GotKeyboardFocus of TextBox -- they are the same. Check your other code for errors.

Comment: I think what's happening is that the MainWindow is running on a new thread, it just happens to be the same ID as the first. That would mean the new thread (with the same ID) has the default thread. How do you get the thread the window is running on?

Comment: I call
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"{System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId} {System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture}");

in App.cs and in MainWindow.xaml.cs

ManagedThreadId is uniq for thread in app

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it to work by setting `System.Globalization.CultureInfo.DefaultCurrentUICulture` to the new culture.